# jQuery AJAX XML in the same structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, xslt

I'm new to using XML and am testing it for a project, (we can't use JSON, we already have existing XML that must be used).

My problem is that I wish to append the data from the XML in the exact same structure that it is displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../xsl/html.xsl" ?>
<htmldoc>
    <heading>
        Odyssey Heading HTML Test in XML.
    </heading>
    <para>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </para>
    <data>GBF79759</data>
    <para>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </para>
</htmldoc>
```

This is a simple example (although the existing XML are much more complex) of some XML markup, I used this as an example because I have a mix of markup that is separated (`<para>'s & <data>` is the prime example here).

Where I have been looking online, everyone has appended data in a non-dynamic way, picking out elements and appending them, what I wish to do is state what every tag is in the XML doc as a HTML element and then append everything. I also wonder if this is something that XSL covers? As I do not have much knowledge in XML/XSL so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an example of my current test JS (non-dynamic way):

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'xml/' + data + '.xml',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml'
}).done(function(xml) {
    console.log("success");
    $(xml).find('htmldoc').each(function() {
        var heading = $(this).find('heading').text(),
            para = $(this).find('para').text();

        $('#main > .content-wrapper > .container').append(
            // XML Structure
            $('<h3>' + heading + '</h3>'), $('<p>' + para + '</p>')
        );
    });
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("error", jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
}).always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to directly append all the XML from inside the `<htmldoc>` element to your page?

Comment: Hello, yes that's exactly what I would like, to literally append the exact structure as is rather than cherry picking certain parts of it.

Comment: XSLT would do a good job at this, you would write a template for each of the input element types creating the corresponding HTML result element, see http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3x for a quick example, it is easily adaptable as you can add further templates and just need to make sure you keep recursive processing up using `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( $.parseXML( xml ) ).find('htmldoc').each(function() {
    var heading = $(this).find('heading').text(),
        para = $(this).find('para').text();

    $('#main > .content-wrapper > .container').append(
        // XML Structure
        $('<h3>'+heading+'</h3>'), $('<p>'+para+'</p>')
    );
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6qot3aw/)

Comment: Sorry, could you summarise exactly how this is different from my current version? On your fiddle it is still appending the specified content rather than everything in the XML in the same structure but not 'cherry picked'.